# Add shadow to image at 0, 0 with Imagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, dropshadow

I have been adding shadows for images with CSS recently, using the code

```
box-shadow:0px 0px 2px 0px #000;
```

This puts a shadow with no offset so it is equal all over the image. How can I do the same thing as this but with Imagick in PHP?

I have tried using the code on the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.shadowimage.php#92502), but when I change the x and y values nothing happens.

Here is the code from the docs:

```
$img = new Imagick("image.png");

$pos = 5;

// The code from the docs
$shadow = $img->clone();
$shadow->setImageBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('black'));
$shadow->shadowImage(80, 3, $pos, $pos);
$shadow->compositeImage($img, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);
header("Content-type: image/png");
echo $shadow;
```

I tried changing the `pos` to `0`, but the shadow looks the same as with `5`. How can I fix this to achieve the same effect as the CSS code above?

Comment: I really can't see what you're trying to do here. ImageMagick is a server-side processing tool, but you've quoted some CSS. Can you post something simple that illustrates your problem more clearly?

Comment: @MikeW Since I am already using a PHP script to process the image before sending it to the client, I want to add the shadow there instead.

Comment: Two things: firstly: if you want help with your PHP script please post it here. Otherwise there's nothing for us to look at. Secondly, you can add shadows in CSS with opacity: `box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);` will give a shadow with opacity of 0.7 - see the rgba() term.

Comment: @MikeW I know how to do it in CSS, but how can I do the same thing as the code above with Javascript?

Comment: @MikeW I have included my code. Can you help now?

Comment: Maybe, but not now. I'll take a look tomorrow.